# Asignar valor al índice de un array con json_decode para imprimir todos los registros

Tags: php, mysql, array, json

Estoy intentando imprimir el valor de un campo de una tabla tipo array o json en concreto de la tabla proveedores el campo services por ejemplo así : **["3", "3", "Marketing", "Diseño Gráfico"]**

A la hora de imprimirlo utilizo MVC y el controlador me envía los datos correctamente.

```
$providers = ProvidersController::getProviders($item, $value);
foreach ($providers as $key => $value): 

                echo $value["name"];
                echo "<br>";
}
endforeach;
```

Sin embargo para imprimir el campo services solo consigo imprimirlo cuando le asigno el valor manual a un registro en concreto, como por ejemplo aquí donde solo imprime el 4:

```
$services = json_decode($providers[4]["services"], true);
                

                    foreach ($services as $key => $value) { 
                        

                        echo $value."<br>";
                
                    }
```

Pero claro necesito imprimir o todos los registros o a veces uno en concreto, he intentado asignar por ejemplo el valor con un for $i pero da error. ¿Qué otra opción podría intentar?

```
$providers = ProvidersController::getProviders($item, $value);
foreach ($providers as $key => $value): 

                echo $value["name"];
                echo "<br>";

                 for($i = 0; $i<=count($providers); $i++){                  
                    
                    $services = json_decode($providers[$i]["services"], true);              

                    foreach ($services as $key => $value) { //Error             
                        
                        echo $value."<br>";
                
                    }
                }

}
endforeach;
```

Comment: como tal el foreach no deberia darte error. Si acaso, puede ser que el json_decode te devuelva un valor false (porque la decodificacion no ha sido correcta) y por tanto luego el foreach te diga que no puede iterar por un null o algo por el estilo. Has probado a poner esa parte del codigo (el json_Decode y el foreach) dentro de un try/catch a ver que te dice el error del catch?

Comment: otra cosa es que ya estas iterando el array $providers con el $value, por lo que no le veo mucho sentido al bulce for del count. tendria mas sentido (para mi) que hicieras `$services = json_decode($value['services'], true);`

Comment: Se me pasó anotar arriba que también probé esta última opción pero me arroja índice indefinido. //$services = json_decode($providers["services"], true); da error índice indefinido.

Comment: no me refiero a $providers, sino al iterado (el $value). puedes mostrarnos una salida del print_r($providers) a ver que contiene? o de print_r($value)

Comment: Exacto, probando de nuevo tal y como dices y revisando los campos ya he logrado encontrar los errores. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente volviendo a probar con **$services = json_decode($value['services'], true);** y gracias a la recomendación de [@Jakala](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7246/jakala) tanto de probar de nuevo como el revisar los campos codificados ya no da error en el índice ya que tenía dos campos **['1', '4', 'Diseño Gráfico']** y al cambiarlo a comillas dobles ya funciona a la perfección. **["1", "4", "Diseño Gráfico"]**

```
$providers = ProvidersController::getProviders($item, $value);

foreach ($providers as $key => $value): 

                echo $value["name"];
                echo "<br>";

                $services = json_decode($value['services'], true);
                
                echo "Servicios del proveedor -> " .$value['id_provider']. " <br>";

                    foreach ($services as $key => $value) {                 

                        echo $value."<br>";
                
                    }

endforeach;
```

Comment: hacia mucho que no veia la nomenclatura foreach/endforeach :)  Te recomendaria que lo pusieras entre llaves (aplicas el foreach interno igual, intenta mantener la misma estructura)